# Mongoose async custom validation not working as expected

Tags: javascript, node.js, mongodb, mongoose, mongoose-schema

in my schema, I'm performing a lot of asynchronous, custom validations. However, validation is not behaving as I expect it to behave. **Even though promises resolve with "false", mongoose continues validation.** According to [their documentation](https://mongoosejs.com/docs/validation.html#async-custom-validators), that shouldn't be the case.

**Sample schema:**

```
    var questSchema = mongoose.Schema({
      questCategory: {
        type: mongoose.Schema.Types.ObjectId,
        required: true,
        validate: {
          validator: async function (v) {
            await data_verificator.checkIfQuestCategoryExists(v);
          },
          message: (props) => `${props.value} is not a valid quest category id.`,
        },
      },
      fulfillmentPeriod: {
        type: String,
        required: true,
        validate: {
          validator: async function (v) {
            await data_verificator.checkFulfillmentPeriod(this.questCategory, v);
          },
          message: (props) =>
            `${props.value} is an invalid value as it violates the limitations set by the quest category.`,
        },
      },
    })
```

Note that the custom validation happens **asynchronously** for those two schema fields. The validation of the `questCategory` field works perfectly fine. If the promise resolves to `false`, validation fails. However, that's not the case for the `fulfillmentPeriod` field. Even though the promise resolves to `false`, the validation succeeds.

I am not sure why I get this weird behavior. If I were to rewrite validation of the `fulfillmentPeriod` to look like the following, everything works as expected again. The promise resolving to `false` causes the validation to fail. Why is that? Why does it work with below code but not with the initial code I pasted above? Is that because I'm referencing another schema field that is validated asynchronously?

```
validator: async function (v) {
  const result = await data_verificator.checkFulfillmentPeriod(this.questCategory, v);
  return result;
},
```

**Just in case this is important, the `checkFulfillmentPeriod` function looks like this:**

```
const checkFulfillmentPeriod = async function (categoryId, period) {
  const connectionManager = require("../configuration").connectionManager;

  var category = await connectionManager.QuestCategoryModel.findOne({
    _id: categoryId,
    availableFulfillmentPeriods: {
      $elemMatch: {
        period: period,
      },
    },
  });

  if (!category) return false;

  return true;
};
```

The function simply checks if there's a category matching the criteria. If so, true is returned. Otherwise false. From what I've found out, the issue doesn't originate in this function but has something to do with mongoose's validation.

***The `checkIfQuestCategoryExists`function looks exactly the same, just with different query settings.***

I've spent hours on this issue and at this point I just don't see any errors anymore.

**I would appreciate any help/advice I could get!**

Comment: what is the content of `this.questCategory` when the validation is triggered?

Comment: @raven it’s the MongoDB ObjectID. I used a console.log() inside the checkFulfillmentPeriod function to test that.

Comment: Did you try adding a return on this lines ? `await data_verificator.checkFulfillmentPeriod(this.questCategory, v);`

Comment: @raven yes :) if I write `return data_verificator.checkFulfillmentPeriod(this.questCategory, v)` everything works fine. Is that how it's supposed to be written? Their documentation states the following: *If your validator function returns a promise (like an async function), mongoose will wait for that promise to settle* - so that means I'm supposed to just return the unresolved Promise as mongoose automatically waits for it to settle?

Comment: The issue is that if you don't write the return it's like you are returning a Promise<void>

Comment: @raven but why is it working in some occasions?

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Can you try this code:

```
var questSchema = mongoose.Schema({
      questCategory: {
        type: mongoose.Schema.Types.ObjectId,
        required: true,
        validate: {
          validator: async function (v) {
            return await data_verificator.checkIfQuestCategoryExists(v);
          },
          message: (props) => `${props.value} is not a valid quest category id.`,
        },
      },
      fulfillmentPeriod: {
        type: String,
        required: true,
        validate: {
          validator: async function (v) {
            return await data_verificator.checkFulfillmentPeriod(this.questCategory, v);
          },
          message: (props) =>
            `${props.value} is an invalid value as it violates the limitations set by the quest category.`,
        },
      },
    })
```

Comment: Thanks for your response. But why did the await without return work in the case of questCategory?

Comment: without a return statement, it will return void. It will never be false and it will always treat as true statement

Comment: can you share `checkIfQuestCategoryExists` in that instead to `return false` you might be throwing an error.

Answer (score 3):

Your validators are missing the return statement thus it is like you were returning a `Promise<void>` and this doesn't make the validation for mongo to trigger. You could either add the return or rewrite your function with a promise being the latter less elegant.

```
new Promise( (resolve,reject) => {
  .....
  resolve(true/false);
});
```